# Batch file: how to format text in specific way?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, formatting

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM Check if a file was dragged onto the script
if "%~1"=="" (
    echo Drag a file onto this script to create a .sound file.
    pause
    exit /b
)

REM Define the name and path of the dragged file
set "SourceFile=%~1"
set "FileName=%~n1"
set "FileExt=%~x1"
set "FilePath=%~dp1"

REM Generate the content for the .sound file
set "SoundFileContent=HD_DATA_TXT 300 & echo. & echo.soundCue & echo { & echo %TAB% %TAB% %TAB% %TAB% sound "%FilePath%%FileName%%FileExt%"; & echo %TAB% %TAB% %TAB% %TAB% range 128.0; & echo %TAB% %TAB% %TAB% %TAB% volume 1.0; & echo }"

REM Create the .sound file
(echo %SoundFileContent%) > "!FileName!.sound"

echo .sound file has been successfully created.
echo don't forget to change pre-made path to corresponding one
timeout /t 5
exit /b
```

This is my .bat file that produces file with .sound extension (I need it for a specific game modding)  which contains this structure:

```
HD_DATA_TXT 300 
 
soundCue 
{ 
    sound "D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Haydee 2\Sounds\customMusic\example.wav";
    range 128.0; 
    volume 1.0; 
}
```

I need to enhance my .bat to delete everything from drive letter till "Haydee 2" to leave only remained path, like that:
`sound "Sounds\customMusic\example.wav";`

I tried to use ChatGPT for resolving the problem but that didn't help. I don't know batch well.

Comment: You aren't trying to resolve a problem, you are trying to get somebody or something to tell you how to do it. That is not what this site is for. Essentially your need is to find out how to modify `%~dp1`/`%FilePath%`, i.e. ```D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Haydee 2\Sounds\customMusic\```. In order to help you with that, in an on topic question, you need to fully explain the criteria by which the dropped file always needs to be shortened.

Comment: There can be used `(echo HD_DATA_TXT 300& echo(& echo soundCue& echo {& echo %TAB% %TAB% %TAB% %TAB% sound "!FilePath:D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Haydee 2\=!!FileName!!FileExt!";& echo %TAB% %TAB% %TAB% %TAB% range 128.0;& echo %TAB% %TAB% %TAB% %TAB% volume 1.0;& echo })>"!FileName!.sound"` for producing the file `example.sound` as wanted by you without a trailing space on each line because of no space left to each `&` which command `echo` outputs too. The environment variable `TAB` is not defined in the posted code!

Comment: I recommend further replacing `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` in the second line by `setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion` and use above the long command line producing the `.sound` file in the __current directory__ (can be any directory) the line `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and after the long line `endlocal`. Otherwise the batch file would fail processing correct a passed file name like `Development & Test 100% (!).wav` which is a valid file name.

Comment: In your code, change `%FilePath%` by `%FilePath:*Haydee 2\=%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, change `%FilePath%` by `%FilePath:*Haydee 2\=%`. This is a *variable replacement* that replaces from *the beginning* of the variable value (because the search string start in asterisk) until the search string and replace it by the replacement string that, in this case, is empty. This effectively works as a *delete* operation of such a part.

Answer (score 0):

> *In your code, change* `%FilePath%` *by* `%FilePath:*Haydee 2\=%` **– Aacini**

Comment: If you want a full answer, you could ask me to post one. In this way, you could select it as Best Answer and give me the credit _and_ the 15 Rep Points!  **`;)`**

Comment: yes post please I would like to